# How to make different paragraphs show up after clicking on something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first question here, I'm very new to coding so please forgive me any mistakes.
So i started learning html/css/some basic javascript recently and I'm trying to build a website just for practice. So one page on it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTEoq.jpg 
And right now i have different html files for each article (linked under the site navigation: Shauna, The First One etc.), so each name of the article takes you to a different page.
What i want to do is to have multiple articles in just one html file, and make them show up/disappear when the name of the article is clicked.
I tried to figure it out somehow in jquery, but i only managed to wrap the article in a div and make it appear when the invisible div is clicked... which isn't much useful.
So is it posibble to do with simple javascript/jquery? If so, the how do i do this?
Thank you all in advance, Michal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO. As it stands this question is too broad (there are a number of different ways you could use to solve this). You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy and practical way is to have one HTML file for each article. It makes your files more organized and easier to find. Otherwise, if your client just want to look at one article the page has to load all articles which may take longer if the client happens to have a slow internet connection.

Comment: Thank you! I guess i'll stick to having an html document for each article then.

Comment: Yeah, that's the most easy and common way of doing it. Almost every other website does this.